# How can I choose a random name from a text file?

Tags: java

I am a beginner java programmer I have managed to create a file and store names on each line, it is in this format
name1
name2
name3
How can I choose a random name and print it? Thanks :)

Comment: I have no idea where to begin, I have searched on google and here but can't find it.

Comment: Have you tried working through a basic Java tutorial, at least enough to read lines from a file? If you don't know enough even to start a Java program, it wouldn't be constructive for someone just to write a full program for you. (Also, is this homework?)

Comment: no its not homework, its for a game im messing around with and im making a lottery system where it adds their name to the file, and I need another method to choose a random name, I have some experience with java but not much about reading and writing from files.

Answer (score 1):

you can either read it all to  a string, split it into an array of strings and use "random" from "math" to generate pseodo random numbers to choose one each interval or you van use the "randomAccessFile" with the above sugestion only that the max random will be the file length and you will be forced to look for the next space to choose the name you want and also handle the case in which you choosed a position in the last

Answer (score 1):

```
String fileName = "...the path and name of your file....";
ArrayList<String> allNames = new ArrayList<String>();
Random r = new Random();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName)); 
while (in.ready()) { 
     allNames.add( in.readLine() );
}
in.close();

String randomName = allNames.get(r.nextInt(allNames.size()));
```

Comment: Thanks so much but how can I keep it from drawing a blank name?

Comment: There are a couple ways. First ensure that your file does not contain blank likes, or add load the string from the in.readline() into a temp string and check if it is empty. If it is not empty add it to the array list. Ignore the line if it is empty. Everything else should work fine.